# How to undelete a partition in testdisk?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, testdisk

How can I undelete a partition that is ~1800 GB in size, I don't want to copy it because my disk size is 2 TB.

I also checked **[Advanced]** option, but this partition didn't show up.

D-Disk is the partition I want to recover/undelete

[image: Testdisk screenshot]

Comment: Please see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for detailed instructions on how to use testdisk.

Comment: After the partition did not show up it most likely can't be recovered using testdisk. Was it encrypted? Was it a Windows "dynamic disk"?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Let's do one step at the time. You wrote that Testdisk doesn't find your partition, so *what* exactly are you trying to undelete? You can't tell to Testdisk "undelete it" if it isn't detected. Your question lacks a lot of important information, most importantly: what kind of file system was on the partition? How did the partition end up being deleted? Was it partially overwritten? Please provide sufficient details so that we can help you.

Comment: The screenshot you are showing has a directory called "D-disk", not a partition.

Comment: I already fixed it. D-Disk was a folder, yes, but the whole folder where D-Disk is was a recovered partition [New Volume] which I recovered by using testdisk.
Here's another thread where I posted the answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325911/how-to-recover-overwritten-partition?noredirect=1#comment573529_325911